# What types/functions should I use to track a file position for random access?

Tags: c, file, io, stdio, fseek

I'm trying to implement a simplified Boyer-Moore string search algorithm that reads its input text from a file. The algorithm requires that I start at a given file position and read its characters backwards, periodically jumping forward a precomputed number of characters. The jumps are computed based on the pattern's length and indices, so I was storing them as type `size_t`. What function should I use to read file characters at specific positions, and what type should I use to store these positions? I'm new to C, but these are the options I've considered:

##### Fseek

I could use `fseek` and `getc` to jump around the file, but this uses a `long int` as its character index. I don't know if it's safe to cast between this and a `size_t`, and regardless, the GNU C manual [recommends against fseeking text streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Portable-Positioning) for portability reasons.

##### Fsetpos

This is supposed to be more portable, but I don't think I can use this to jump forward or backward an arbitrary number of characters.

##### Binary Stream

I could get around the `fseek` compatibility issue by opening the file as a binary stream. But I don't know if this could cause other compatibility issues when dealing with pattern/input text, and anyways, this doesn't solve the issue of casting between `long int` and `size_t`.

##### File Descriptor

I could use file descriptors instead of streams. But then I need to cast between `size_t` and `off_t`, and I don't know how safe that is. I would also give up `FILE`'s buffering, which I'm not sure is advisable. I could try to roll my own buffering, or maybe use an alternate library, but this seems like a massive pain.

My first implementation passed the input text as a command line argument, so it didn't deal with file IO at all. But I don't think this would scale well for large text inputs, and the more I've read about file IO the more stuck I feel. What do you suggest?

Comment: I'd just `mmap()` it or read the entire file into freshly malloced memory.

Comment: (or a search algorithm that doesn't look backwards)

Comment: There's a lot of information missing from your question that would help you to get much better answers. How large are your input file(s)? How long are the lines, if any?  What operating system are you running on?  Does your code need to be portable to other operating systems?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I plan to test on input files as large as I can. I'm not making assumptions about line length. I'm running x64 linux but would like to make the code portable since I'm trying to learn about C in general.

Comment: How long can the search string be? If is at most `LONG_MAX`, you can use `fseek` with `SEEK_CUR` regardless of the file length. Boyer-Moore will not require you to reposition a distance greater than the string length. (In any case, for portability, you should open the file as binary to avoid problems seeking.)

Comment: IMHO the issues about portability are quite easy to handle. Managing text files for *strings* the control characters will be ignored or used as separators, then having a '\n' as ASCII LF, CR + LF, or LF + CR, isn't an issue. The conversion between `size_t` and `long int` is then significant for *integer overflows*, and before of that you will have to consider why `fseek` uses a signed offset and why/how you would use an unsigned `size_t` to move

Answer (score 3):

**`size_t` ⇔ `long` conversions**

If `long` is large enough for a file offset, and if your `size_t` value represents a file offset, then there's no problem with converting between these two. (And no need for an explicit cast.)

**Portability**

So is `long` actually large enough for a file offset? `long` is well known to be its minimum size on Windows, 32 bits. Even in 64-bit programs. So there could be portability issues if you plan on handling files with a size of 2 GiB or greater while using the `fseek` interface. You should have no problems with smaller files.

**Jumping forward or backward an arbitrary number of characters**

The CRLF line endings used in Windows will bite you here, no matter what interface you use.

It's very likely you can work around this problem. It depends on your definition of "character", and it might depend on how precise the jump needs to be. You haven't provided enough information for us to help you.

Comment: I plan to test the program on files larger than 2 GiB. The algorithm searches for instances of a substring in a text input, and the substring has to match byte for byte. I need precise jumps so I can iterate through the substring's characters and compare them to possible matches within the input text.

Comment: Missing info should be provided in the question, not in the comments. /// Since you want byte-for-byte matches, this means CR and LF have no special meaning. So no issues with line endings being two bytes on Windows. Just make sure to open the file in binary mode. /// But `long` won't be large enough on Windows, so `fseek` won't be good enough if you want a portable solution.  You might need to use different functions on different OS. `fseek` where `long` is 64+ bit, or `lseek` where `off_t` is 64+ bit, or `SetFilePointer` if available (Windows), and fail elsewhere. // Will adjust answer.

Comment: Correction, if you're doing relative seeks, 32-bit sizes will be enough if the seek distance is no more and 2 GiB, even if the file is larger.